# Monitor CPU and bandwidth usage of cpu and save to csv

Tags: monitor, cpu, process, bandwidth, csv

I would like to monitor a specific process. I need to know timestamp, CPU usage (%) and Bandwidth (tcp upload and download in % or byte/s) of this process.

I have tried something like this:

`ps -Ao time,pcpu,comm  --sort=pid | head -n 2`

But time is not equal date. For network if stat looks goed but it doesnot monitor process.

Further I would like to put it a CSV file like this:

```
Date; CPU%; Upload%; Download%;
```

How can I manage this?

Thank you.